# Renaming an iOS Framework after it's been built

Tags: ios, frameworks, rename, dyld, xcframework

I've built a framework from modified open source C++ code for use in another development sdk. Apps are not able to use this sdk if they have another sdk that also depends on this framework. How can I re-namespace this framework *after* its already been built (changing `MyFramework.xcframework` -> `MyNewFramework.xcframework`).

After renaming all of the references I could find, I was still getting a linker error on install: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[app] Reason: image not found`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires updating the name of the framework everywhere:

1. Open `MyFramework.framework` directory (if using an XCFramework, this will require opening the `.xcframework` directory and repeating these steps for the `.framework`s for both the `x86_64` and `arm64` architectures.)
2. Open the `Info.plist` and change the `Bundle name` and `Executable file` to `MyNewFramework`. You will also want to update the `bundle id`
3. Open `Modules/module.modulemap`. Change the uses of `MyFramework` to `MyNewFramework`:

```
framework module MyNewFramework {
  umbrella header "MyNewFramework.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

4. Open the `Headers` directory and for each and every header file in there, you'll need to change all of the imports of other local header files: `#import <MyFramework/Something.h>` -> `#import <MyNewFramework/Something.h>` (I would suggest a global find and replace for `#import <MyFramework/`).
5. Change the file in the `Headers` directory `MyFramework.h` to `MyNewFramework.h`
6. Change the name of the executable found in the framework directory from `MyFramework` to `MyNewFramework`
7. Once navigated to the `MyFramework.framework` directory, run the command: `otool -l MyNewFramework | grep rpath`. It should echo something like this: `name @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework` as one of the options. Copy this path.
8. Using the command copied from step 6, Replace the instances of `MyFramework` with `MyNewFramework` run this command: (changing `@rpath/MyNewFramework.framework/MyNewFramework` if different from what you'd copied)

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/MyNewFramework.framework/MyNewFramework MyNewFramework
```

9. Confirm that renaming the rpath was successful by running `otool -l MyNewFramework` again and checking that the path has been updated to `MyNewFramework`.
10. Rename the name of the entire framework from `MyFramework.framework` to `MyNewFramework.framework`
11. If using an XCFramework, navigate outside of the architectures to the `Info.plist` found directly in the `.xcframework` directory. Under `AvailableLibraries` in both `Item 0` and `Item 1` change `LibraryPath` from `MyFramework.framework` to `MyNewFramework.framework`.
12. If using an XCFramework, don't forget to rename the name of the outermost directory from `MyFramework.xcframework` to `MyNewFramework.xcframework`.
13. To ensure there aren't any hanging references, delete derived data (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`). Make sure to tear down your dependencies and re-integrate them with the renamed one. (For cocoapods, this involves updating your Podfile or podspec with the new framework name, then running `pod deintegrate && pod install`.)

Whew! What a job! Go fix yourself a nice cup of something.

Note: verify that this doesn't cause any issues while building and exporting your app. If so, consider disabling Bitcode if that's a viable option for you.

Comment: Can You share how to do it for Swift xcFramework?

Comment: I would imagine it would look fairly similar, except that you probably wouldn't be able to use the `dSYM`s and `BCSymbolMap`s.

Comment: One thing to note is that while doing this I'd ran into some issues with damaging the code signatures. You'll want to verify that it works by building and exporting a binary. Disabling bitcode can also fix that issue if that's a viable option.